# (Prestashop 1.7) Show shipping costs only after country address is added

Tags: prestashop

Do you know how to add and show shipping costs in checkout summary, ONLY after an address (with county) is added/selected, on Prestashop 1.7.6?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. You make your country have county as requirement.
2. You edit the corresponding .tpl (which serves the shipping cost)

```html
{if !isset($address)}
    <span class="alert alert-warning">
        {l s='Choose address to see the shipping cost'}
    </span>
{else}
    {* Here the actual content *}
{/if}
```

Regards,
Konstantinos A. Kogkalidis

Comment: Thank you 
Unfortunately this snippet shows a message if the address is not present BUT summary still adds the value of the shipments to the total sum. I need to avoid shipping costs are added to total before to assign it a carrier.

Comment: Understood. Then you have to check the point where the shipping cost increases the total one. "Play" with the Context::getContext() object and check if carrier has been set. It's a really tough time to check myself the whole procedure (I would have done it) but I believe giving food for thought is a better approach for your learning curve.